# Variable in string disappears when redirecting with header()

Tags: php, string, variables, smarty

I have a SMARTY form and would like to pass a variable(set from the url/referrer) from the form page to the thank you page. So what I do:

1. I open my page with the form: `example.com/index.php?variable=blabla`
2. I get the variable and form the thankyou page URL
   `$urlconv = 'example.com/thankyou.php?variable=' . $_GET["variable"];`
3. When the form is filled and submit is clicked the form redirects to the thank you page: `header('Location: ' . $urlconv);`

I even echo `$urlconv` on the first page to be sure that I've constructed the url correctly together with the variable. And it shows it correctly.

Unfortunatelly the redirect omits the variable for some reason. It goes only to `example.com/thankyou.php?variable=` for some reason...

Maybe by the time I call the redirect the variable is gone, so my question is can I somehow hardcode the variable in `$urlconv`? Because if the echo is showing it right and then the riderect omits it it means it has saved only a shortcut to the variable and not the actual value in the string, right?

I have very basic programming skills.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `urlencode` function. Along with that, if its within your browser, kindly omit the example.com and try using a relative link.
So

```
$urlconv = '/thankyou.php?variable='.urlencode($_GET["variable"]);
```

I've tried this right now, and it did work.

```
    $urlconv = '/start.php?variable='.$_GET["variable"];
    header('Location: '.$urlconv);
```

---

2nd solution: Try using javascript redirection. Also use double quotes while assigning $urlconv, as in  `$urlconv = "/thankyou.php?variable=".urlencode($_GET["variable"]);`

```
<?php
    echo "<script>location.href='".$urlconv."';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: tried using urlencode but it didn't work, also I'm using only digits and letters for testing

Comment: @phpwannabe Edited. Try using relative links, and tell me what happens if you do.

Comment: tried with relative, variable is still missing when redirected

Comment: yes, just tried that and it is working. But you are making me test alone something that is working in the first place. What is not working is the variable disappearing.

Comment: @phpwannabe No I just wanted to make sure its not a problem with your server. Sorry for the inconvenience. Updated a new solution, see if it works.